# how to change the elements of group of lists after a certain index?

Tags: python, list

I have one main decider list which will tell the specific index and 3 saving lists which contain 11 cost values in them and one opex escalation which will be used to increase the value

```
savingYear = [0,4,8] #decider list
saving1 = [22,323,142,234,23,23,45,45,6,67,122] #saving list
saving2 = [12,333,421,734,253,263,445,45,611,6127,122]#saving list
saving3 = [12,133,433,234,233,263,465,45,62,6712,1242]#saving list
opexEscaltion = 0.1
```

Now what I have to do is to take the last number of `savingYear` which is `8` and this 8 will be the specific position in all the `savingList`. So 8th position in `saving1`, `saving2` and `saving3` is `6, 611, 62` respectively. Now what I want to is that I want to take these and apply `opexEscalation` on them and fill rest of positions(9th and 10th) in all the `saving lists`. So it would be like:

```
9th element in saving1 = 6*1.1 #1.1 because 0.1 is in percentage
9th element in saving2 = 611*1.1
9th element in saving3 = 62*1.1
10th element in saving1 = 9th element*1.1
10th element in saving2 = 9th element*1.1
10th element in saving3 = 9th element*1.1

so final saving list will be something like:
saving1 = [22,323,142,234,23,23,45,45,6,6.6,7.26] #saving list
saving2 = [12,333,421,734,253,263,445,45,611,672.1,739.31]#saving list
saving3 = [12,133,433,234,233,263,465,45,62,68.2,75.02]#saving list
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: why 10th element after 9th element it should be 5th element?

Comment: no, I am taking only the last element of savingYears which is 8 and changing all the elements after this position in saving Lists

Comment: Why *saving1* last element is *7.62*?

Comment: oh sorry it should be 7.26 which is 10% increase of the 9th element.

Comment: But `67 * 1.1 = 73.7` !

Comment: I explained that in my calculations that I am changing all the elements after 8th position and their value will be like : for eg:- in saving1 9th element will become 8th element * 1.1 which 6*1.1

Comment: so 9th element is now 6.6 which will replace the original 67

Comment: that's why 10th element will be 6.6*1.1 not 67*1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as that

```
year = savingYear[-1]

for item in [saving1, saving2, saving3]:
    for index, _ in enumerate(item[year + 1:]):
        item[year + 1  + index] = round(item[year + index] * 1.1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def fun(lst, start, end):
    for idx in range(start, end):
        lst[idx + 1] = round(lst[idx] * 1.1, 3)
        
fun(saving1, savingYear[-1], len(saving1) - 1)
fun(saving2, savingYear[-1], len(saving2) - 1)
fun(saving3, savingYear[-1], len(saving3) - 1)
```